# 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails' in transaction

Tags: mysql, database

I got three tables, a parent one (called **profiles**) and two tables one can consider a child (**values** and **url**). This is just a test to play around so don't mind missing SQL injection security.

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `profile` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `url_hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`profile`,`url_hash`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `urls` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `url` text NOT NULL,
 `title` text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `urls_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `values` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `seller` text NOT NULL,
 `seller_language` text,
 `quality` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `note` text,
 `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `count` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `values_mtg_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I'm executing the following three queries as transaction (surrounding autocommit(false), commit() & rollback() omitted):

```
$db->query('INSERT INTO profiles(id, profile, url_hash) 
VALUES (null, ' . $profile . ', "' . md5($url) . '")')
or throwException(...);

$db->query('INSERT INTO urls(id, url, title) 
VALUES (' . mysqli_insert_id($db) . ', "' . $url . '", "' . $c->data('title') . '")')
 or throwException(...);

$db->query('INSERT INTO values(id, seller, seller_language, quality, 
note, price, count) 
VALUES (' . mysqli_insert_id($db) . ', "'. $seller .'", "'. $seller_lang .'", 
'. $qual .', "'. $notice .'", '. $price .', '. $ount .')') 
or throwException(..);
```

Resulting in

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'Query failed (table: values): 
(1452) Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`crawler`.`values`, CONSTRAINT `values_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES
`profiles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)'
```

and I just don't get why. It is stating the corresponding **id** in the parent table is missing. If that's the case why does the second query work since its table **urls** got the very same foreign key relationship to table **profiles** like table **values**?

**Edit**: there is a huge flaw in my database design, regarding the FK in **values** which can't be unique. Gonna think about it tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error resulted from my flawed database design (what I never thought of).
In **values** id was unique while my script tried to INSERT multiple values with the same id.